# Etale algebra whose local rank is constantly zero is the zero algebra

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

While working through a proof of [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.04148.pdf) paper, at the middle of page 46, the author seems to claim the following is true:

> Let $A\rightarrow B$ be an [etale map of rings](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00U0). Suppose that for every prime $P\subset A$ we have
>   $$
> \kappa(P)\otimes_{A}B=0
> $$
>   where $\kappa(P)$ is the residue field at the prime ideal $P$.
>   Then $B=0$.

The only thing I seem to be able to extract from here is that $PB=B$ for all primes $P$ of $A$, which does not seem enough for any kind of conclusion, since $B$ is not necessarily a finite $A$-module.
Of course if we would have some Noetherianity or some projectivity assumptions , perhaps one can then use the connections between the [different definitions of rank of a module](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/153659/different-definitions-of-a-rank-of-a-module). But else I don't know how to use that $A\rightarrow B$ is an etale ring map.

Comment: This doesn't use étale at all. If $\mathfrak q \subseteq B$ is a prime, then it has a preimage $\mathfrak p = f^{-1}(\mathfrak q) \subseteq A$. But then $\kappa(\mathfrak p) \otimes_A B$ maps to $\kappa(\mathfrak q)$, contradicting the hypothesis. We conclude that $\mathfrak q$ does not exist, i.e. $B$ is the zero ring. Geometrically, the assumption is that all fibres of $\operatorname{Spec} B \to \operatorname{Spec} A$ are empty, and the conclusion is that $\operatorname{Spec} B$ is empty.